# Need help for extracting historical prices using chainlink api

Tags: python, chainlink

This is my first time i am using a api call for implementing on project for predicting the avalanche price feed for machine learning to get the historical data for 2 years.

I want api call from chainlink websites where there is alvalanche price feed below is the url whre i want to fetch the data for predicting a machine learning model for historical 2 years data

https://docs.chain.link/docs/avalanche-price-feeds/

```
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://kovan.infura.io/v3/<infura_project_id>'))

addr = '0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331'
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=addr, abi=abi)
validRoundId = 18446744073709562301

historicalData = contract.functions.getRoundData(validRoundId).call()
print(historicalData)
```

The above is mentioned in the document in the chainlink documentation but i'm not sure how to extract day-wise historical prices of the cryptocurrency

Answer (score 0):

This Chainlink external adapter provides a JSON object containing the aggregator Phase ID & answerRound.  inputs are the Proxy address of price feed and the unix timestamp you are requesting.

https://github.com/pappas999/historical-price-feed-data/tree/main/src/historical-price-ea